# How do 確認したところ and 全長15メートルほどの古い木造船が見つかり relate here?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:

> 青森海上保安部によりますと、巡視船２隻を出して**確認したところ全長15メートルほどの古い木造船が見つかり**、外国人とみられる男性２人が乗っていました。

For full context, see [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190113/k10011776551000.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-main_003).

My attempt at translation:

> "According to the Aomori Coastal guard office, they sent out 2(?) patrol boats and the moment they confirmed that a boat of about 15 meters overall length was found and two men were aboard."

The problem is that the only way I can interpret 確認したところ so far is the way I did above. However, it's obvious that I can't really make a meaningful attribute to 木造船 of it anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 確認したところ simply means "When they checked".

> 青森海上保安部によりますと、巡視船２隻を出して確認したところ全長15メートルほどの古い木造船が見つかり、外国人とみられる男性２人が乗っていました。
>   According to the Aomori coast guard office, they sent out 2 patrol boats and, when they checked, they found a wooden ship around 15m long with two men on board who were thought to be foreigners.

I changed the intransitive 見つかり to transitive in English to make the translation sound less awkward.